# How to get the stock location for a line item from an complete order in spree commerce ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

In spree commerce is there any way to get the stock location of the line items.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly You can find you complete order let say you order number is R001023223
Then

```
order = Spree::Order.complete.find_by_number('R001023223')
```

then find line item as like this

For single line item stock location

```
line_item = order.line_items.first
stock_locations = line_item.variant.stock_locations
```

For all stock locations of line items:

```
stock_locations = order.variants.map(&:stock_locations).flatten
```

that's it...!!!

Comment: for all stock location for line items of given order i can editing in your post